# Filter a DataTable using Date value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want filter data table using date and display in grid view. Given below is my code, but its not showing any result in gridview. I am passing this `03/18/2015` date.

**Sample DB :**

```
SlNo   Name   Submited_Date
----  ------  -------------
1      abc    3/18/2015 6:24:48 PM
2      xyz    3/18/2015 6:48:23 PM
3      pqr    3/20/2015 3:14:18 AM
```

**Code :**

```
protected void btnSubmit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
CommunicationTableAdapters.tbl_splited_detailsTableAdapter sd;
sd = new CommunicationTableAdapters.tbl_splited_detailsTableAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = sd.GetSiteDetails(Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text));
GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**SQL :**

GetSiteDetails:

```
SELECT        SlNo, Name, Submited_Date
FROM          tbl_splited_details
WHERE         (CONVERT(DATETIME, Submited_Date) = @date)
```

Comment: Using `=`, you get an exact match, meaning that the date values must be identical up to the millisecond.

Comment: @HansKesting : The DB contains date and time, how can I filter using date?

Comment: In your `where` you mention `uploaded_date`. Did you mean `Submited_date`? Or is that a column you didn't show?

Comment: @HansKesting : Yes....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to ignore the time portion of the `DateTime`?

If you use SQL-Server 2008 or higher you can convert the `datetime` to `date`:

```
SELECT        SlNo, Name, Submited_Date
FROM          tbl_splited_details
WHERE         (CONVERT(DATE, uploaded_date) = CONVERT(DATE, @date))
```